# Texture doesn't show up in final render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I am rendering an animation in Cycles and the texture doesn't show up in my final render. The texture shows up in the material preview and the render preview but not when I render it. It is the only texture that this happens to as well.

I have everything UV unwrapped and the texture is mapped to the UV via a texture coordinate and a mapping node.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Blend file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/kyx0mw6zkj9wo8t/Submission.blend/file

Screenshots:
[image: Render]
[image: Veiwport]

Here is the node setup:
[image]
[image]
[image: All Nodes]

Comment: Please, when you ask a question about shading, add a screenshot of the viewport it would be very helpful for others to understand the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a plane at the same location in the scene as the real floor, and it is rendered on top of it.
[image]

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that. ‍♂️

Comment: @Bluffyyy not a problem, happens to everyone =)